# NSInvocationOperation Cancel usage

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, nsinvocationoperation

Is it right if I cancel an `NSInvocationOperation` inside the operation?
example:

.h file:

```
//defined in the interface
NSInvocationOperation *op1;
NSOperationQueue  *loadQueue;
```

.m file:

```
-(id)init{
    op1 = [NSInvocationOperation new];
    loadQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
}

-(void)downloadData{
    op1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadServerResponse:) object:newerRequest];
    [loadQueue addOperation:op1];
}
```

Now I have a method to download data from the server. I added a condition to check if there is an error. If so I'm cancelling that operation inside the method and calling back the same method upon retrieving the new login token.

```
- (void)loadServerResponse{
    if(server_error){
        [op1 cancel];
        //fetch login token again
        [self downloadData];
        return;
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, referencing `op1` (which I'm assuming is a class-level ivar) is a Bad Thing™ on multiple levels, the first of which is NSOperationQueue dispatches your operation onto a background thread, so `op1` will (at best) be copied into that thread's context and no longer reference the original operation you were attempting to cancel.

I think you don't need to worry about canceling the operation, given the logic you have shared. You specifically seem to want to call `downloadData` after canceling, and there's no guarantee that will happen if you cancel the operation first. I would just remove the call to cancel the operation, and continue on. Normally you only cancel a running operation from an external source (say if you receive a notification that your application will enter background state).

Comment: if what you said is true then how could one ever access a NSInvocationOperation object and call cancel on it (or any other method) ?

Comment: A good question - in this specific example the OP was trying to cancel from within the method that the operation was attempting to execute. This means that he/she was attempting to reference an object across thread boundaries, which is generally considered a bad idea. If you want to call cancel, you should call it from the original thread that enqueued the operation, OR subclass NSOperation and manage it internally.

Comment: that makes sense. I am doing something similar but my cancel happens from outside (not from the method-to-execute) and I think that should be fine to do. I handle isCancelled within the method-to-execute